# How to how to read grayscale mask image using numpy?

Tags: python, image, numpy, semantic-segmentation

I was going through someones code on semantic segmentation try to learn some techniques but I could figure out one particular section which I will really need an explanation
Here is the entire function

```
def DataGen():
    img_ = []
    mask_ = []
    c1 = []
    y1 = []
    for i in range(len(image_)):
        image = cv2.imread(image_[i])
        image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        image = image / 255
        image = cv2.resize(image, (height, width), interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA)  # image
        cc1 = cv2.resize(image, (height // 2, width // 2), interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA)  # resize image

        mask = cv2.imread(mask_id[i], 0)
        mask[np.where(mask == 0)] = 198
        target = np.zeros([966, 1296, 2])

        target[:, :, 1][np.where(mask == 149)] = 1
        target[:, :, 0][np.where(mask == 76)] = 1

        mask = cv2.resize(target, (height, width), interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA)
        yy1 = cv2.resize(target, (height // 2, width // 2), interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA)
        mask = np.expand_dims(mask, axis=-1)
        print(mask)
        yy1 = np.expand_dims(yy1, axis=-1)
        img_.append(image)
        mask_.append(mask)
        c1.append(cc1)
        y1.append(yy1)
    img_ = np.array(img_)
    C1 = np.array(c1)
    Y1 = np.array(y1)
    mask_ = np.array(mask_)
    mask_[np.where(mask_ != 0)] = 1
    Y1[np.where(Y1 != 0)] = 1
    return img_, C1, mask_, Y1
```

This is where I got bit confuse

```
mask = cv2.imread(mask_id[i], 0) # mask is read in grayscale Point-1
mask[np.where(mask == 0)] = 198

target = np.zeros([966, 1296, 2]) # numpy is define Point-2
target[:, :, 1][np.where(mask == 149)] = 1
target[:, :, 0][np.where(mask == 76)] = 1

mask = cv2.resize(target, (height, width), interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA)
```

How does the mask gets into the numpy array in the target variable that is initialize in Point-2?

Comment: Maybe be a bit more selective in who you try to learn from... someone who can be bothered to comment their code and uses the correct, defined, legible, maintenance-free constants like `cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE` rather than ugly manifest constants like the `0` in `cv2.imread()` which give you no idea what they are for.

Comment: Yeah you are right, Anyways I was able too understand every other section of the code except this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figure it long since so I decided to answer it ... may be it will help a others.

`target[:, :, 1][np.where(mask == 149)] = 1

target[:, :, 0][np.where(mask == 76)] = 1
`

This "np.where(mask == 149)" can simply be remove and replace with any integer value as an index. The author choose that index from MxN mask image array and set it. there it is simply a variable declaration in numpy and can rewritten as

`
target = np.zeros([966, 1296, 2])

target[:, :, 1][100] = 1

target[:, :, 0][75] = 1
`